# O que o Model pode fazer em questão de validação no MVC?

Tags: php, mvc, validação, engenharia-de-software, controller

Em um projeto MVC desenvolvido em PHP, eu deveria validar o que no *model* e o que no *controller*? *Hash* de senhas eu estou fazendo no método *set* das classes *model*.

Certas validações que não são retornadas para o usuário eu acredito que deveria fazer no *model* como tirar espaços, transformar letras em maiúsculas, retirar acentos... Mas as que o usuário precisa mudar e submeter novamente eu acredito que deveriam ficar no *controller*. O que seria uma boa prática nestes casos?

Comment: Se for levar ao pé da letra, o *controller* não deveria validar, apenas controlar o fluxo, e o *model* seria o responsável pelas regras de negócio - tipo validação. Algumas validações eu mantenho no *controller* por comodidade e facilidade.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 9):

Você pode fazer o que você quiser. Ninguém pode dizer para você que é o criador do software o que você deve fazer. A não ser, obviamente, se houver um motivo técnico para fazê-lo. Esta é a boa notícia. Esqueça boas práticas, esta expressão devia ser abolida do desenvolvimento de software, isto só causa entendimento errado das coisas.

Dito isto, entenda que essas recomendações de padrões são para organizar melhor seu código. Por isso você deve fazer escolhas que produzam uma melhor organização, que te deixe confortável para trabalhar desta forma, permitindo que dê manutenção de forma mas simples.

Tenho más notícias: saber exatamente o que fazer em cada situação depende de experiência (de qualidade, não basta quantidade). O máximo que você pode fazer quando ainda não tem é perguntar para quem tem. Mas tenha em mente que isto só dá certo para casos específicos e que nada garante que a pessoa vai entender o problema. E mesmo que entenda, também não é garantido que ela esteja comprometida em lhe fornecer a melhor solução, mesmo que superficialmente ela queira.

Respondendo sua pergunta aqui, de forma geral, as validações devem ser feitas no modelo mesmo. Isto é o que diz a "lei" ( :D ) do MVC.

Mas nada impede você de colocar validações que você ache pertinente no controlador, algumas podem fazer sentido. Algumas podem ter a ver com a entrada de dados em si e não com os dados persistidos de forma mais direta. Ou seja, você está validando o fluxo. Então pode ser na visão também.

Você não pode validar algo no modelo que dependa do que você está fazendo para entrar o dado.

Alguns dirão que viola o princípio do MVC. Pode ser, mas não vejo uma forma melhor para fazer.

Claro que você pode fazer isto de formas mais inteligentes, pode injetar essa validação de forma externa e não codificar internamente ao controlador. Pode organizar o código para **atender os objetivos** do MVC ao invés de seguir fórmula pronta. Pode compartilhar código de validação entre o modelo e o controlador. A validação provavelmente deveria ser uma entidade separada.

Mas pode fazer quando a validação precisa ocorrer também no modelo. Alguns dos exemplos que você citou precisaria ser validado no modelo (se você só validar no controlador, alguém poderá passar por cima disto e o modelo aceitar dados escritos de forma desorganizada), então você poderá criar um código mais modular que possa ser usado para validar o modelo e para se antecipar no controlador. Claro que esta necessidade depende de algo que vai um pouco além do MVC. De qualquer forma se você está querendo validar algo na página, terá que fazer em JS, certo? O modelo é em PHP? O controlador também? Percebeu que terá que fazer duas validações que validam a mesma coisa? Não existe mágica.

Note que o padrão MVC diz como deve ser o fluxo de trabalho. Ele não diz exatamente onde deve estar o código. O código não precisa estar em uma destas partes propriamente dita. Onde a validação deve estar? Em qualquer lugar. O que você quer saber é onde ela deve ser invocada. E tem motivos para invocar tanto no modelo quanto no controlador, depende do caso, sem falar que muitas vezes estará na visão, provavelmente de forma adicional.

Enquanto não entender completamente o que é o MVC, porque ele existe, o que ele te traz de bom, você nunca poderá usar o padrão de forma consciente e não poderá tomar decisões importantes, caso a caso, como deve ser.

Nós temos algumas informações aqui em [diversas perguntas sobre o tema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc). Muitas são muito específicas e talvez não lhe sirva para muita coisa, outras podem ajudar te dar experiência usando experiência dos outros. Algumas podem ter respostas ruins. Em outros tempos eu diria que as ruins seriam mal votadas, mas hoje não consigo dar essa garantia.

A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) é outro lugar óbvio para começar estudar o assunto.

Um [artigo interessante voltado para o PHP](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/php/archive/mvc-intro.html).

Uma [wiki de padrões da computação](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewController) que vale a pena.

[Pergunta no Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/127624/389) sobre o assunto que dá diversas visões e caminhos para obter mais informações.

[Artigo do Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) com visão mais ampla sobre o assunto.

[Exemplo razoavelmente detalhado](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mvc-for-noobs--net-10488).

Isto é só um início para começar entender o padrão, não pare por aí. [Leia este e-book](https://stefanoborini.gitbooks.io/modelviewcontroller/content/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

No modelo MVC você deve fazer as validações de regras de negócios dentro do Model, deixando assim o controller responsável apenas pelo fluxo, ou seja, princípio da responsabilidade única.
O Model deve impulsionar sua aplicação e não o controller.

Comment: Resposta correta. Ressalto apenas que você só referiu às validações de regras de negócio (sim, estas precisam estar no Model), mas há também validaçoes de aplicativo - estas fazem sentido não estarem no Model e sim no Controler.