# Técnicas para manter consistência dos dados no front-end

Tags: html, segurança

**Exemplo**: Em um formulário, alguns campos (`input`) são carregados via ajax a partir de um `select`. A `option` selecionada será usada no *back-end* para validação desses campos.

Entretanto, o usuário pode carregar uma determinada opção, preencher seus campos e, intencionalmente, alterar o valor (no browser) da tag `option` selecionada para um outro valor válido, por exemplo, e encaminhar para o servidor.

Como garantir a consistência dos dados vindo de um formulário HTML? Quais técnicas/métodos são essenciais?

> Compreendo que isso pode ser tratado com determinadas condições no back-end. Minha busca é por quais são as melhores práticas. Por exemplo, penso que para cada `option`, devo guardar um token identificador em um `input[type=hidden]`, assim poderia checar facilmente se os dados são referentes à opção selecionada.

Comment: Esquece, náo tem nada que pissa garantir dados no cliente http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/67911/101

Comment: Não está claro para mim quais informações você quer garantir. Sua metodologia também não fala se você deseja tratar ataques de 'bots' ao formulario. Descreva melhor o fluxo de dados entre o get e o post. O que seria essa Option e quando ela é selecionada? É um parametro visivel para o usuário ou é uma variável de controle interna do sistema?

Answer (score 2):

A forma correta é a que você ja está fazendo, tentando validar diretamente no browser e ainda assim ter uma outra validação no servidor antes de executar os comandos enviados pelo usuário.

Esse tipo de problema não é exclusivo de HTML mas qualquer aplicação que tenha um cliente e um servidor, onde nós fazemos a validação no cliente para evitar conexões desnecessárias com o servidor e ainda assim outra validação no servidor de qualquer dado que for enviado pelo cliente, aí sempre vai haver essa dupla validação.

O que eu fiz e recomendo pra evitar repetição de código foi colocar toda a validação no modelo de dados que era compartilhado entre ambos, então eu poderia chamar Pessoa.Validar que me retornaria true ou false indicando se passou, fora que teria também métodos para pegar listas de erros do objeto validado.